# capturing edited file name from duplicated file

Tags: applescript

I copy a a file to a new folder then rename it. Next I want to open it:-

```
set myNewFile to duplicate myFile to myNewLocation
set the name of myNewFile to myNewFileName
open myNewFile
```

The first 2 lines above work but the open command doesn't work because it can't find the file since I renamed it. I want to do something like:-

```
open myNewLocation & myNewFileName
```

myNewLocation is a valid path, myNewFileName is just a string, I have all the data I need but I can't work out how to construct a valid usable path from the two items.

Alternatively I could maybe change the name at the same time as I duplicate the file, before I save it to myNewFile. I've tried:-

```
set myNewFile to duplicate myFile to myNewLocation with name myNewFileName
```

and

```
set myNewFile to duplicate myFile to myNewLocation with properties {name:myNewFileName}
```

Neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFile to file "Mac OS X:Users:JD:Desktop:testStart.txt"
set myNewLocation to (path to desktop as text)
set myNewFileName to "testEnd.txt"

set myNewFile to duplicate myFile to myNewLocation

set the name of myNewFile to myNewFileName

tell application "Finder" to open file (myNewLocation & myNewFileName)
```

Comment: The key to this answer is identifying the myNewFileName as a file for finder.  You can also  use:  open file myNewFileName of myNewLocation

Comment: @markhunte's version works directly with my script (my path is an alias) or if i convert the path to text as per adayzdone's version that works. thanks, both.